# There's a way to put an icon on the options menu in android 3+

Tags: android, user-interface, menu, android-optionsmenu

There's a way to put an icon on the new options menu style in android? ps. I don't want use the actionBar for that.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). The reason for the ActionBar is to provide consistent UI to help the user feel more comfortable with the app. If I fully understand what you are asking then you shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

> There's a way to put an icon on the new options menu style in android?

No, sorry.